# MarketingCloudSDK iOS 8.0.13 Security Flaws

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush-ios

We have integrated Salesforce Marking Cloud SDK for iOS v.8.0.13 as part of our connectivity implementation between our App and Salesforce Cloud.
While running Security Scans on our iOS Mobile App which also uses SFMC SDK v.8.0.13, few medium Security flaws are reported.

I have attached screenshots for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can you please review this and let us know if there is any plan to address this in upcoming SDK Release.

Currently, these flaws are blocking our release as per our security guidelines and wont allow us to use this SDK.

If any additional info. required, feel free to reachout.
Appreciate your support and guidance on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Please work through your account team to engage with Salesforce's security team if you have concerns about a security scan you've conducted with your application.

Comment: Hello, Above screenshots contains file names and line # from SDK where the flaws are reported by Static Code Scan tool.